# How to select just unique values into a mysql table based on the value in one column?

Tags: mysql

I have table named x

Here is the sample data in table x

Column1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**
Column2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
Column3

a                                ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**                                        b***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c

a2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_***b2****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c

a3_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_***b3****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c2

a4_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****b4****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_c3

The result I need in a new table is:

Column1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**
Column2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
Column3

a3_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_***b3****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c2

a4_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****b4****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_c3

I tried importing the values to a new table and applying a unique index on column 3 but the result i get out of it is

Column1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**
Column2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
Column3

a_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_***b****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c

a3_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_***b3****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_c2

a4_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****b4****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_c3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE Column3 NOT IN 
  (SELECT Column3 FROM x GROUP BY Column3 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```